# Special probability distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, inequality, probability-distributions

> If $p(x)$ is a probability distribution with non-zero values on $[0,+\infty)$, what conditions on $p(x)$ yield $\int_0^{\infty}p(x)\log{\frac{ p(x)}{(1+\epsilon)p({x}(1+\epsilon))}}dx \leq c \epsilon^2$, where $c$ is a constant and $0<\epsilon<1$.

The inequality above is actually a Kullback-Leibler Divergence between distribution $p(x)$ and stretched version of it ${(1+\epsilon)}p({x}{(1+\epsilon)})$. I have found out that this inequality holds for Exponential, Gamma, and Weibull distributions and I am interested to know if that works for a larger class of probability distributions.

Any idea what does that inequality mean?

---

Before, I thought this inequality holds for all distributions and I was looking for proofs, but I realized this is not true in general by counter examples such as the one introduced as an answer bellow in which lets
$1/\beta =1+\epsilon$ and equivalently considers $\int_0^{\infty}p(x)\log{\frac{\beta p(x)}{p({x}/{\beta})}}dx \leq c (1-\frac{1}{\beta})^2$.

Comment: why is it interesting?

Comment: Oh, it was interesting for me to find an upper bound for Kullback Leiber, which is hard.

Comment: You may find useful [this](http://core.ac.uk/download/files/296/10834996.pdf) paper: "Some Upper Bounds For Relative Entropy And Applications", by Dragomir et al.

Comment: @CarlosMendoza Thanks a lot. I am reading it. Can you point a special part of it?

Comment: Page 6, Theorem 2 seems very similar to what you want.

Comment: @CarlosMendoza it works for probability mass functions, I need something similar for the continuous case.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think thus is true in general.

Let's construct a case where the relative entropy is infinity. Let's consider a special case where $\beta = 2$. For each set $A$, let

$\bar A = \{2x|x\in A\}$.

Now, we can pick a sequence of segments on $R^+$, $A_1, A_2, ..., $ such that $A_1, \bar A_1, A_2, \bar A_2 ...$ do not intersect each other.

Now assign constant density on these sets, so that,

$P(\bar A_i) = \frac{1}{4^i}$ and

$P(A_i) =  \frac{1}{2}e^{-4^i}P(\bar A_i)$

Note that the density $p(x) = \frac{P(\bar A_i)}{\mu(\bar A_i)}$ and $p(x/2) = \frac{P(A_i)}{\mu(A_i)}$ for $x\in \bar A_i$, where $\mu(A)$ is the standard borel measure of $A$.

Also note that $\mu(\bar A_i) = 2\mu(A_i)$ by construction, so we have,

$log(\frac{p(x)}{\frac{1}{2}p(x/2)}) = 4^i$

on $\bar A_i$ and

$\int_{(\cup \bar A_i)}p(x)log(\frac{p(x)}{\frac{1}{2}p(x/2)})dx = \infty  $

On the remaining set, just assign, say, the exponential distribution, scaled by some constant to make $p$ a probability.  By renormalization, you can prove that

$\int_{(\cup \bar A_i)^c}p(x)log(\frac{p(x)}{\frac{1}{2}p(x/2)})dx >-C $

for some constant $C$.

So, overall, the relative entropy is $\infty$.

Comment: I said the support of p (x) is (0,inf). Has value in all area.

Comment: So, your case cannot happen.

Comment: I see. Still I think we can  construct counter examples. By the way, what is $E(x)$?

Comment: Expected value of X, Mean of X

Comment: New construction in the answer.

Comment: The pdfs you defined are not such that \sum P(A_i) = 1.

Comment: $\sum P(A_i) + \sum P((\bar A_i))<1$, as I said, on the remaining set, assign pdf to make $P$ a probability

Comment: This statement is wrong: log(p(x)/p(x/2))=4^i

Comment: Added some explanations.

Comment: Thanks again. But $\beta <1$ in my problem statement.

Comment: Same idea should work, just reverse the role of  $A$ and $\bar A$, you get a counter example for $\beta=1/2$

Comment: Thanks so much for your taking the time. I am not sure if we could build the other points successfully here "On the remaining set, just assign, say, the exponential distribution, scaled by some constant to make p a probability".

Comment: how about the continuous case?

Comment: Continous case, no problem. Monotonic case might be challenging.

Comment: I would like to thank you for taking the time to give me an answer about this problem. I didn't accept your answer since it was not complete and needed more clarification, but it was really helpful to me.